# rails active record relationship... inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have multiple user roles:

```
  enum role: { staff: 0, clinician: 1, admin: 2 }
```

Staff users create patient records and belong to a university.

**Staff Concern**

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module StaffUser
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    belongs_to :university
    has_many :patients
    has_many :referral_requests
    validates :university_id, presence: true, if: :staff?
  end
```

**Patient Model**

```
  class Patient < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user, -> { where role: :staff }

  belongs_to :staff_clinician, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'staff_clinician_id'
    end
```

**University Model**

```
class University < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :staffs
```

The first user in the table is a staff user, so in console I can do something like User.first.patients.count to get a count of all the patients created by that staff user. I want to be able to do something like University.first.patients.count, but when I try I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `patients' for #<University:0x007f8dc9444b30>
```

Do I need to explicitly create a belongs_to has_many relationship between the Patient model and the University model and put a university_id in my patients table to be able to return a value? In other words, can rails infer from a Staff User belonging to a university that any patients created by a staff user also belong to that university, or no?

Thanks!

Comment: That is what I would do.

Comment: If you add the relationship between the patient and the staff that created the patient (e.g., does patient belongs_to staff?) then perhaps we can help you sort it out. But, assuming you have such a relationship, then no, you should not have to put a university_id in your patients table. (And, IMO, it would be a bad idea.)

Comment: Thanks! I just added the Patient model. In my application, a staff user who creates a patient record may or may not be the staff clinician of that patient, which is why I have it set up to belong to staff_clinician with a staff_clinician_id stored in the patients table.

Comment: see this question for more detail on the implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432707/rails-multiple-active-record-relationships-between-two-models

Comment: You might want to tweak the formatting on "class Patient < ApplicationRecord" in your question.

Comment: Thanks Tom - I tweaked the formatting. Jvillian can you tell if my relationship is set up correctly to be able to do this?